# Modified and creation time for file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to get the modified and creation time for file in powershell. This commandd:

```
forfiles /m *.* /c "cmd /c echo @file @ftime"
```

gives the modified time. What is the attribute name for for creation time? I tried `ctime` without sucess, serched in google, did not find. Note that I need to get creation time and modified time side by side together.

Answer (score 0):

The *forfiles* command you're using has nothing to do with PowerShell and can be used in a plain command prompt window as well. Also if you had read what  `forfiles /?` says you would have known that printing file creation time is not supported.

For a PowerShell-specific solution you could use something like the following:

```
foreach ($objFile in Get-ChildItem "C:\Windows\*.exe") { '"' + $objFile.Name + '" | ' + $objFile.CreationTime.ToShortTimeString() + ' | ' + $objFile.LastWriteTime.ToShortTimeString() }
```